# SwiftUI: How to focus DatePicker

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swiftui

I'd like to focus the DatePicker programmatically: tapping on a button for example.

```
DatePicker(
    "Picker",
    selection: $content.date,
    displayedComponents: .date
)
Button("Focus", action: { ??? })
```

I tried the `.focused()` modifier with no luck, as it seems to be only working for TextField.

Comment: This is not currently possible with pure SwiftUI.

Comment: You could raise a feedback using the feedback assistant and could request for this.